# How to list TLS 1.2 ciphersuites im openssl 1.0.2g

Tags: ssl, encryption, openssl, tls1.2

In openssl man page for openssl 1.0.2g, the command for listing the ciphersuites:

```
openssl ciphers [-v] [-V] [-ssl2] [-ssl3] [-tls1] [cipherlist]
```

Although the server that is running openssl 1.0.2g is TLS 1.2, this version of openssl does not provide TLS 1.2 in the command (unlike openssl 1.10).

My question is how can I list TLS 1.2 ciphersuites in openssl 1.0.2g?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option -tls1 includes TLSv1, TLSv1.1 or TLSv1.2. 
The documentation talks about it.
https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/ciphers.html

Comment: I am also looking for an answer to the same OP question. I looked at the change log. Nothing straight about TLS version support I could see. I need to know if openssl 1.1.0 support SSLv3 or not. Can you point to me any reference  or statement in the log? I could not find any.

Answer (score 0):

All the ciphersuites in OpenSSL 1.0.2g can be used in TLS1.2 so there is no need to use a special flag for this.

Note: this is not the case in OpenSSL 1.1.0 (hence the addition of the flag). There are some ciphersuites (i.e. those based on "single" DES and IDEA) that are deprecated by the standards for use in TLSv1.2 (but actually still work if both client and server support them). OpenSSL 1.0.2 does not respect that deprecation, but OpenSSL 1.1.0 does (DES ciphersuite support is removed completely, and IDEA based ciphersuites will not be offered in TLSv1.2).